# get hourly chart of sales of particular date in single query

Tags: mysql, report, query-optimization

i am having an invoice table

i want to get the chart report of sales by hour on particular date

[image]

there is large amount of data of single days by 10 branch

i have used query of between using time slot loop but isn't working because of too much load on database due to multiple time slot & branch loop

```
SELECT SUM(total_payble) as totalPayble, sum(invoice_pax_no) AS TotalPax,count(invoice_id) as TotalInvoice from bkt_invoice where (invoice_created_date between '2016-09-20 17:00:00' AND '2016-09-20 18:00:00') AND invoice_is_void = 0 AND invoice_branch_id = '1'
```

as above query i have to fire this query 10 times for 10 branches also plus multiple time slots like from morning 7 to night 12

so is there any possibilities where i can create a query which can return the result as below in single query

Branch A

[image]

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I'm not clear what you are after here. Do you want a query which returns all branches by hour, or a way of building a query which will pick a single branch using dynamic sql so you don't have to manually intervene, or you after an automated process to run the query or are you saying you need help optimising your current query or what?

Comment: @P.Salmon I need help to build a query which can return branch data by 1 hour intervals of particular day just like branch A having sales 8 To 9 : 36.00   , 9 to 10 : 50.00 , 10 to 11 : 74.00 like this i need results so there will be no multiple queries so it will optimize automatically

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from customer;
+------+------+
| id   | name |
+------+------+
|    1 | abc  |
|    2 | def  |
|    3 | ghi  |
|    4 | jkl  |
|    5 | jkl  |
+------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from bkt_invoice;
+----+------+---------------------+-------+
| id | cid  | dt                  | value |
+----+------+---------------------+-------+
|  1 |    1 | 2018-01-29 07:00:00 |    10 |
|  2 |    1 | 2018-01-29 23:00:00 |    20 |
|  3 |    1 | 2018-01-29 07:30:00 |    10 |
|  4 |    1 | 2018-01-29 11:30:00 |    10 |
|  5 |    1 | 2018-01-29 11:45:00 |    10 |
|  6 |    2 | 2018-01-29 07:30:00 |    10 |
+----+------+---------------------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The inner sub query below will generate all the hours for which a bkt_invoice might exists, the outer query simply groups and sums.

```
select s.id,s.name,
    case s.hr
        when 7 then '07-08'
        when 11 then '11-12'
    else 'undefined'
    end as hr,
    ifnull(hour(dt),'') bhr,ifnull(sum(value),0) TotalValue,ifnull(count(b.id),0) as NofInvoices
from
(
select id, name ,hr.hr
from customer as branch
cross join
(
select 7 as hr union select 8 union select 9 union select 10 union select 11 union select 12 union
select 13 as hr union select 14 union select 15 union select 16 union select 17 union select 18 union
select 19 as hr union select 20 union select 22 union select 23 union select 24
) hr 
) s
left join bkt_invoice b on b.cid = s.id and hour(dt) = s.hr
group by s.id,s.name,s.hr,hour(dt)

+------+------+-----------+-----+------------+-------------+
| id   | name | hr        | bhr | TotalValue | NofInvoices |
+------+------+-----------+-----+------------+-------------+
|    1 | abc  | 07-08     | 7   |         20 |           2 |
|    1 | abc  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    1 | abc  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    1 | abc  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    1 | abc  | 11-12     | 11  |         20 |           2 |
|    1 | abc  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    1 | abc  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    1 | abc  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    1 | abc  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    1 | abc  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    1 | abc  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    1 | abc  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    1 | abc  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    1 | abc  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    1 | abc  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    1 | abc  | undefined | 23  |         20 |           1 |
|    1 | abc  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    2 | def  | 07-08     | 7   |         10 |           1 |
|    2 | def  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    2 | def  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    2 | def  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    2 | def  | 11-12     |     |          0 |           0 |
|    2 | def  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    2 | def  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    2 | def  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    2 | def  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    2 | def  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    2 | def  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    2 | def  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    2 | def  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    2 | def  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    2 | def  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    2 | def  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    2 | def  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    3 | ghi  | 07-08     |     |          0 |           0 |
|    3 | ghi  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    3 | ghi  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    3 | ghi  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    3 | ghi  | 11-12     |     |          0 |           0 |
|    3 | ghi  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    3 | ghi  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    3 | ghi  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    3 | ghi  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    3 | ghi  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    3 | ghi  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    3 | ghi  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    3 | ghi  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    3 | ghi  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    3 | ghi  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    3 | ghi  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    3 | ghi  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    4 | jkl  | 07-08     |     |          0 |           0 |
|    4 | jkl  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    4 | jkl  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    4 | jkl  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    4 | jkl  | 11-12     |     |          0 |           0 |
|    4 | jkl  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    4 | jkl  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    4 | jkl  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    4 | jkl  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    4 | jkl  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    4 | jkl  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    4 | jkl  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    4 | jkl  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    4 | jkl  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    4 | jkl  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    4 | jkl  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    4 | jkl  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    5 | jkl  | 07-08     |     |          0 |           0 |
|    5 | jkl  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    5 | jkl  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    5 | jkl  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    5 | jkl  | 11-12     |     |          0 |           0 |
|    5 | jkl  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    5 | jkl  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    5 | jkl  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    5 | jkl  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    5 | jkl  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    5 | jkl  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    5 | jkl  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    5 | jkl  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    5 | jkl  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    5 | jkl  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    5 | jkl  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
|    5 | jkl  | undefined |     |          0 |           0 |
+------+------+-----------+-----+------------+-------------+
85 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```